# Question about conditional probability in Dirichlet Process

Tags: bayesian, stochastic-processes, dirichlet-process

Let $DP(\alpha_0, G_0)$ be a dirichlet process from which we sampled a distribution $G$.
Furthermore we sample $\theta_1, ..., \theta_n$ from $G$ and let $A_1, ..., A_m$ be a partition on the support of $G$

In addition let: $n_i$ = $\sum_{j = 1}^n1_{A_i}(\theta_j)$

My *Question* is why it holds that:

$p(\theta_1, ..., \theta_n|G(A_1), ..., G(A_m)) = \prod_{i = 1}^mG(A_i)^{n_i}$

Comment: I think the question needs a little bit of clarification: what is $f$?

Comment: Changed it to $p$ (the posterior)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not getting it: how is it that $p$ is the posterior if $\theta$ are observed? I would guess that $p$ is some sort of likelihood, conditioned on a partial information about $G$

Comment: Sorry that was faulty By me: the Term expresses the probabilty for n samples from G